# Xhr request shows pending for a certain format in all the browsers on my machine

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, browser, xmlhttprequest

In my windows machine I run a simple fileserver that serves certain files from a folder. I access these files via **chrome/firefox** browsers

For a certain file format (**In my case ".bin" file**) the xhr request always stalls with a message saying "**pending**". But If I rename the file extension to "**.cbin**" and reload the page on browser again it works.

Why are the browsers preventing a certain file to be loaded ? All of this used to work a month back without issues (ie loading the bin files). I have disabled my **antivirus** too.

Any help would be invaluable. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching on the web and experimenting I realized that the browsers have recently added rules by which they block downloads of certain files (exe,dmg,zip,gzip,bin) etc on a http connection for security reasons.

Hope this will help someone who faces the same issue.

You can read more about this issue [here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webappsec/2019Apr/0004.html) and [here](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-chrome-engineers-want-to-block-some-http-file-downloads/).